# Get list of photo galleries on Android

Tags: android, image, gallery, mediastore

I'm looking for:
A list of the existing photo gallery names (hopefully their top thumbnail as well)
The contents of the gallery (I can then load thumbnails and full size as needed)

How would I go about getting a list of the "Galleries" (don't know if that's the proper term in android for the groupings of images visible in the Gallery app...) and their contents? I need access to the gallery in it's structure without using the existing gallery display (I'm creating a totally new one, not an over layer to the photo requestor etc.)

I assume MediaStore.Images is where I need to be but I don't see anything that will give me the groupings...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Groupings are defined by `MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME`. Here is the sample code to list the images and log their bucket name and date_taken:

```java
// which image properties are we querying
String[] projection = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN
};

// content:// style URI for the "primary" external storage volume
Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

// Make the query.
Cursor cur = managedQuery(images,
        projection, // Which columns to return
        null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
        null,       // Selection arguments (none)
        null        // Ordering
        );

Log.i("ListingImages"," query count=" + cur.getCount());

if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    String bucket;
    String date;
    int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

    int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);

    do {
        // Get the field values
        bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
        date = cur.getString(dateColumn);

        // Do something with the values.
        Log.i("ListingImages", " bucket=" + bucket 
               + "  date_taken=" + date);
    } while (cur.moveToNext());

}
```

Comment: AH! it works like a raw database query. perfect example code thank you!

Comment: how to get image path ? for each dateToken ?

Comment: managedQuery is deprecated, use context.getContentResolver().query, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12714830/3324388

Comment: @Peter Knego ... This works great, but it is little slow when the number of images > 1000. Any solution to that will be highly appreciated

Comment: >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q (It is a sad story!)

Comment: @Mr.Lemon What do you sad story for Android Q? I have a problem where cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME) is returning null on Android Q

Comment: Hi, anyone knows why this solution doesn't work for Android Q?

Answer (score 39):

```
/**
 * Getting All Images Path
 * 
 * @param activity
 * @return ArrayList with images Path
 */
public static ArrayList<String> getAllShownImagesPath(Activity activity) {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
    ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    String absolutePathOfImage = null;
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

    cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    column_index_folder_name = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
    }
    return listOfAllImages;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to your manifest.

Answer (score 24):

**Here is the full solution in few simple steps:**

The next few steps will guid you how to create a `Vector` that will hold the albums found on a given device. Every Album will hold a preview image as well an inner `Vector` that will hold all the images of the Album.

1. Create an object that will hold the images once extracted from storage. We are going to call it `PhoneAlbum`. This is how it's going to look:

   ```
   public class PhoneAlbum {

       private int id;
       private String name;
       private String coverUri;
       private Vector<PhonePhoto> albumPhotos;

       public int getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId( int id ) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName( String name ) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getCoverUri() {
           return coverUri;
       }

       public void setCoverUri( String albumCoverUri ) {
           this.coverUri = albumCoverUri;
       }

       public Vector< PhonePhoto > getAlbumPhotos() {
           if ( albumPhotos == null ) {
               albumPhotos = new Vector<>();
           }
           return albumPhotos;
       }

       public void setAlbumPhotos( Vector< PhonePhoto > albumPhotos ) {
           this.albumPhotos = albumPhotos;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create an object that will hold the images within the album called: `PhonePhoto`

   ```
   public class PhonePhoto {

       private int id;
       private String albumName;
       private String photoUri;

       public int getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId( int id ) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getAlbumName() {
           return albumName;
       }

       public void setAlbumName( String name ) {
           this.albumName = name;
       }

       public String getPhotoUri() {
           return photoUri;
       }

       public void setPhotoUri( String photoUri ) {
           this.photoUri = photoUri;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create an interface to handle the extracted images upon completion. We are going to call it `OnPhoneImagesObtained`. Here it is:

   ```
   public interface OnPhoneImagesObtained {

       void onComplete( Vector<PhoneAlbum> albums );
       void onError();

   }
   ```
4. Create a new class: `DeviceImageManager`

   ```
   public class DeviceImageManager {

   }
   ```
5. Once you created `DeviceImageManager`, add the following method:

   ```
   public static void getPhoneAlbums( Context context , OnPhoneImagesObtained listener ){
       // Creating vectors to hold the final albums objects and albums names
       Vector< PhoneAlbum > phoneAlbums = new Vector<>();
       Vector< String > albumsNames = new Vector<>();

       // which image properties are we querying
       String[] projection = new String[] {
               MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
               MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
               MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
       };

       // content: style URI for the "primary" external storage volume
       Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

       // Make the query.
       Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(images,
               projection, // Which columns to return
               null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
               null,       // Selection arguments (none)
               null        // Ordering
       );

       if ( cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0 ) {
           Log.i("DeviceImageManager"," query count=" + cur.getCount());

           if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
               String bucketName;
               String data;
               String imageId;
               int bucketNameColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                   MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

               int imageUriColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                   MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

               int imageIdColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                   MediaStore.Images.Media._ID );

               do {
                   // Get the field values
                   bucketName = cur.getString( bucketNameColumn );
                   data = cur.getString( imageUriColumn );
                   imageId = cur.getString( imageIdColumn );

                   // Adding a new PhonePhoto object to phonePhotos vector
                   PhonePhoto phonePhoto = new PhonePhoto();
                   phonePhoto.setAlbumName( bucketName );
                   phonePhoto.setPhotoUri( data );
                   phonePhoto.setId( Integer.valueOf( imageId ) );

                   if ( albumsNames.contains( bucketName ) ) {
                       for ( PhoneAlbum album : phoneAlbums ) {
                           if ( album.getName().equals( bucketName ) ) {
                               album.getAlbumPhotos().add( phonePhoto );
                               Log.i( "DeviceImageManager", "A photo was added to album => " + bucketName );
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                   } else {
                       PhoneAlbum album = new PhoneAlbum();
                       Log.i( "DeviceImageManager", "A new album was created => " + bucketName );
                       album.setId( phonePhoto.getId() );
                       album.setName( bucketName );
                       album.setCoverUri( phonePhoto.getPhotoUri() );
                       album.getAlbumPhotos().add( phonePhoto );
                       Log.i( "DeviceImageManager", "A photo was added to album => " + bucketName );

                       phoneAlbums.add( album );
                       albumsNames.add( bucketName );
                   }

               } while (cur.moveToNext());
           }

           cur.close();
           listener.onComplete( phoneAlbums );
       } else {
           listener.onError();
       }
   }
   ```
6. Now all you have left is to render the images to screen. In my case I like to use `Picasso`. Here is how I do it:

   ```
       Picasso.with( getActivity() )
                   .load( "file:" + mPhoneAlbums.get( i ).getCoverUri() )
                   .centerCrop()
                   .fit()
                   .placeholder( R.drawable.temp_image )
                   .into( mAlbumPreview );
   ```
7. Don't forget to add a permission to read external storage in your manifest:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   ```

That's it. You are good to go!
Good luck!

Comment: This is very helpful!

Comment: is there any reason why you would prefer a vector over a list?

Comment: All the methods of Vector are synchronized. But, the methods of ArrayList are not synchronized. In the project I wrote it in, it was needed. You can use ArrayList as well.

Comment: Wow!! thank you so much, it saved me so much time, its actually works perfectlly

Answer (score 7):

I've found a way to get albums without iterating over every photo.

```
 String[] projection = new String[]{
                "COUNT(*) as count",
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                "MAX (" + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + ") as max"};

 Context context = ServiceProvider.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
 Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                "1) GROUP BY (" + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                null,
                "max DESC");
```

cursor will contain as much elements, as distinct bucket name exists, and also you can get count inside every cursor position to get count of images inside album

here example:

```
if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                //gets image path, it will always be a latest image because of sortOrdering by MAX date_taken
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                //gets count via alias ("as count" in projection)
                int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("count"));

                //do you logic here
                ...

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
```

Some explanation about selection param:

contentResolver adds parentheses when compiling resulting query for sqlLite, so if we make selection like

"GROUP BY " + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME

it will be compiled as "WHERE (GROUP BY bucket_display_name)" and will cause SQLiteException at runtime. Otherwise if we make selection like

"1) GROUP BY (" + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME

it will be compiled as "WHERE (1) GROUP BY (bucket_display_name)", which is correct

Answer (score 3):

Download the source code from here ([Get all images from gallery in android programmatically](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/get-all-images-from-gallery-in-android-programmatically/))

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gv_folder"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></GridView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package galleryimages.galleryimages;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<Model_images> al_images = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;
    Adapter_PhotosFolder obj_adapter;
    GridView gv_folder;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gv_folder = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv_folder);

        gv_folder.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value",i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }else {
            Log.e("Else","Else");
            fn_imagespath();
        }



    }

    public ArrayList<Model_images> fn_imagespath() {
        al_images.clear();

        int int_position = 0;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
            Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

            for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
                if (al_images.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    boolean_folder = true;
                    int_position = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean_folder = false;
                }
            }


            if (boolean_folder) {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_images.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);

            } else {
                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
                obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);

                al_images.add(obj_model);


            }


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("FOLDER", al_images.get(i).getStr_folder());
            for (int j = 0; j < al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().size(); j++) {
                Log.e("FILE", al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().get(j));
            }
        }
        obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(getApplicationContext(),al_images);
        gv_folder.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
        return al_images;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        fn_imagespath();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The app was not allowed to read or write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android with Compose, this works well too!

```
@Composable
internal fun rememberMediaPhotos(
    context: Context
): List<MediaPhoto> {
    val photos = remember { mutableStateListOf<MediaPhoto>() }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(coroutineScope) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH
            )

            val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"

            val query = context.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
            )

            query?.use { cursor ->
                val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val heightColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT)
                val widthColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH)

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                    val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
                    val height = cursor.getFloat(heightColumn)
                    val width = cursor.getFloat(widthColumn)
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        id
                    )

                    photos.add(
                        MediaPhoto(
                            name = name,
                            uri = contentUri,
                            size = Size(width = width, height = height)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return photos
}
```

I have created a library to make this easier:
https://github.com/nabla-run/Compose-gallery-picker