# android get thumbnail of image stored on sdcard whose path is known

Tags: android, thumbnails

Say I have an image stores at path `"/mnt/images/abc.jpg"`. How do I get the system generated thumbnail bitmap for this image. I know how to get the thumbnail of an image from its Uri, but not from its file-path

Comment: You can simply create thumbnail video and image using ThumnailUtil class of java

    Bitmap resized = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath()), width, height);

Answer (score 24):

You can try with this:

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnail(ContentResolver cr, String path) throws Exception {

    Cursor ca = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID }, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] {path}, null);
    if (ca != null && ca.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = ca.getInt(ca.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        ca.close();
        return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null );
    }

    ca.close();
    return null;

}
```

Comment: thanks you sir! and obvious, but someone might needs it, if you want to show bigger images, use MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND

Comment: Best solution that I have found. Thank You very much, this should be accepted answer.

Comment: MINI_KIND is used for : 512 x 384 thumbnail
MICRO_KIND is used for : 96 x 96 thumbnail

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `Uri` from a file like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/images/abc.jpg"));
Bitmap thumbnail = getPreview(uri);
```

And the following [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916724/448625) gives you the thumbnail:

```
Bitmap getPreview(Uri uri) {
    File image = new File(uri.getPath());

    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), opts);     
}
```

Comment: I think using `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), Long.parseLong(_imageUri.getLastPathSegment()),
                type, null);` would be a better option, since the system most of the time caches the thumbnails

Comment: your method to get the uri doesnot seem to be working correctly because for a file with path "/mnt/sdcard/2011-12-02 11.22.50.jpg" the actual uri is ontent://media/external/images/media/556 where as the Uri.fromFile(...) method returns file:///mnt/sdcard/2011-12-02%2011.22.50.jpg

Answer (score 4):

It could be a alternative ways as other had already mentioned in their answer but Easy way i found to get thumbnail is using [`ExifInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

```
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getPath());
    byte[] imageData=exif.getThumbnail();
    if (imageData!=null) //it can not able to get the thumbnail for very small images , so better to check null
    Bitmap  thumbnail= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData,0,imageData.length);
```

Comment: In some cases, it is not work. Not better than get from Image Store as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Yaa when BitmapFactory wont able to decode byte array then only .

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create thumbnail video and image using ThumnailUtil class of java

```
Bitmap resized = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath()), width, height);


 public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)
```

Added in API level 8
Create a video thumbnail for a video. May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported.

Parameters
filePath    the path of video file
kind    could be MINI_KIND or MICRO_KIND

[For more Source code of Thumbnail Util class](http://www.rogerethomas.com/blog/generating-square-cropped-thumbnails-in-android-java)

[Developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use android **Bitmap class** and its **createScaledBitmap** method.

method descroption:

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

example of using:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path);
int origWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
int origHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, origWidth / 10, origHeight / 10, false);
```

**decrease the source file like you want.** In my example I reduced it 10 times.