# Save image in imageView using R.id.image not R.drawable.image into database

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to save an image in an `ImageView` to the database using R.id not R.drawable because the image can change(because its a camera picture). l can not use the path to the image to save because the gallery might be tampered around with.

```
HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(this);  
byte[] image4 = HotOrNot.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, R.id.imageView2));
entry.open();
entry.createEntry(image4);
entry.close();

public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: when i use R.id.imageView2 it gives me errors but if i use a sample r.drawable.image it works but l want to use  R.id.imageview2

Comment: with BitmapFactory.decodeResource u only can use actual image from the drawable. how about creating a bitmap and then convert it to drawable ? ?

Comment: R.id and R.drawable values can also change since they are generated. You should save the image itself, for example using Base64 encoding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android How to save camera images in database and display another activity in list view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941637/android-how-to-save-camera-images-in-database-and-display-another-activity-in-li)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that, `R.drawable.image` is the `ID` of the actual image. And `R.id.imageView2` is the `ID` of the `ImageView`.

Your argument is that the image you want to store can change. So in that case, what you can do is use `yourImageView.getDrawable()`, so that you will get the current image in the `ImageView` and then convert it to `Bitmap` using this

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
byte[] image4 = HotOrNot.getBytes(bitmap); // Your code from here.
```

Comment: thanx a lot but since i am very new to this i kind of understand but can i have more clarity.

Comment: more clarity on what? can you be a bit more specific as to which part did you not understand?

Comment: ok,when you said "what you can do is use yourImageView.getDrawable()".Sorry but im still new.So how do i implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is represented by `R.id..` is an id for a resource type from the project's pre compiled assets. I don't think you can get an `id` value for an image taken with the Camera.

Also note that the type of `R.id..` is an int.

I know the above is not an answer. If you want to take an image using the Camera and save it in the database, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941637/android-how-to-save-camera-images-in-database-and-display-another-activity-in-li) question in SO. Hope it helps.

Comment: ok,so how can i save the image in the imageview to the database because i am taking a picture and insert it into a imageView and from the imageView to the database.