# Losing a lot of quality on image crop

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera-intent

I'm capturing an image from camera and then saving it do sqlite database.

After that I allow user to crop it. After the whole process quality is very very poor.

I'm testing it on Nexus7 and I know it's front camera is poor but right after crop app opens, the picture is very small. It takes like 1/5 of s creen in the crop activity and I don't know why.

**This what happens `onActivityResult` (capturing taken picture)**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");          
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
        if (!doCrop(imageUri)) saveNewAvatar(bitmap);
    }
}
```

**And here is `doCrop(Uri uri)` method:**

```
private void doCrop(final Uri imageUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

    int size = list.size();

    intent.setData(imageUri);

    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

      if (size == 1) {
          Intent i = new Intent(intent);
          ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

          i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

          startActivityForResult(i, CROP);
      }
}
```

After the whole process picture is very very small.

**EDIT:**
Did some research and followed code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941637/android-how-to-save-camera-images-in-database-and-display-another-activity-in-li)

Ended up with this:

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: I'm using android-cropimage library in case standard crop is not avalible.

Answer (score 5):

There are many wrong (as in: *maybe works, but that's not the way you do such things on Android*) things about your code, but the source of the problem is that you read the image from the `data` key in extras. The version in extras is just a miniature, and it is of very low quality.

What you need to do is change the way you invoke the camera. This is slightly counter-intuitive, but you do not get the url to the picture taken from the camera, but just the opposite: pass an url to the camera and it will try and put the picture there.

The url might point to the SD card or to you own `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I removed a lot of ifs and trys for simplicity. This seems like a correct direction, if You could only provide me with some sample code...

Comment: fdreger Care to elaborate some more?