# Using shared preferences with images

Tags: button, background, sharedpreferences

Ok guys, I can use shared preferences to save text so next time the app is loaded that text is displayed/restored

But is there a way to do this with Button Background Images?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly you wan't to do, but you can obviously save an image(Bitmap) as a byte array. Also you can compress it using Bitmap's compress method. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942102/3260244) can be of some help if you are sure about using shared prefs for saving image.

Comment: Well the button and all relate to image views so I guess it is the image views I want saving. I was trying to save the image path and recall it on start up. The user defines the image from preset selections within the app. And I just want the app to always remember the selections any time is closes and recall it on start up

Comment: Then in that case, you can save the name of image with button name as key in shared prefs and recall on startup! No point in saving the whole image.

Comment: Cheers will IGive this a go when I get home and let you know

Comment: Ok, after running preliminary tests it looks like it will work but I am having trouble getting the image location/name from the ImageView

Comment: never mind, I found it, I had one small piece of bad code. I will share the solution later when I get a little more time

Comment: Because the images are stored local I just set boolean to trigger event for r.drawable.image name and then saved to presences. Not ideal and I assume a little process heavy but it does the job

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Boolean changeImageBg = intent.getBooleanExtra("change", false);
        if (changeImageBg) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_left_2small);
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("done", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            String string;
            string = "arrow_up_left_2small";
            editor.putString("aul", string);
            editor.commit();
```

Ok, so above is the saving side. Since my image is part of the app I was able to save it easily once I understood what to do.
I will be using boolean to trigger differnt images based on the active boolean I will be able to trigger the save for the appropriate image, I will at some point look at passing this code over the app so I can use less code.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("done", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String imageName = prefs.getString("aul", "");
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageResource(resID);
    }
```

Here is where I call the file path and use it on create to re apply the pictures