# Is there a way to increase the size of WindowCursor in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

i am using a Cursor to query SQLite database in my android application. But cursor size is limited to 4 MB i suppose. (I have 6 blob columns in a row and each one of them is nearly 1.5 MBs so it is 9MBs in total.)

Is there a way to increase the maximum size of this cursor or should i seperate the columns in a single row in order to lower the size of a single row?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to increase the size of WindowCursor in Android Studio?

Yes, one of it's [constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow#CursorWindow(java.lang.String,%20long)) takes a long for the number of bytes i.e.

```
public CursorWindow (String name, long windowSizeBytes)
```

> Is there a way to increase the maximum size of this cursor or should i seperate the columns in a single row in order to lower the size of a single row?

Not with the available methods *(a Cursor uses CursorWindows and hence the difference)*.

**However**, the recommended approach is to not store such large amounts of data in the database, but to store the data as a file and instead store a reference (e.g. the file's path) to the file where the data is stored.

- You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107489/sqliteblobtoobigexception-row-too-big-to-fit-into-cursorwindow-while-writing-to/57109330#57109330) and some of the links informative

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@SuppressLint("DiscouragedPrivateApi") 
Field field = CursorWindow.class.getDeclaredField("sCursorWindowSize");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(null, 10 * 1024 * 1024); //the 10MB cursor size
```