# Failed to read row 0 sqlitedatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How to fix it?

```
W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 2108731 bytes, free space 17752 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 2108731 bytes, free space 2096480 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 9 columns.
```

Comment: If you are storing big blobs, you might look into seeing if the android sqlite bindings provide an interface to the [incremental blob i/o API](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html) functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing row data (typically one of the columns contains a media object (e.g. an image) as a blob) in the database that is too large to be handled by the Cursor. That is an attempt is being made to retrieve **2108731** bytes which is beyond the 2M (2097152 bytes) allocated to a Cursor Window.

You cannot use the android SDK's Cursor methods (without modification) to retrieve such a large amounts of data, even though you can store such an amount.

The fix is to store that data behind the blob (generally images) as a file and to then store a reference to the file (e.g. it's path or part thereof) in the database.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954175/how-can-i-insert-image-in-a-sqlite-database/53954280#53954280) has examples (based on images) and a more comprehensive overview of the issue.

Alternately, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321154/how-to-use-images-in-android-sqlite-that-are-larger-than-the-limitations-of-a-cu) shows a way you could store such an image or images by splitting the data in parts.