# Saving png image in database through android app

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, android-image, android-database

I want to save image using my developed app into mobile what is the best way to it.

I was trying to save via sqlite but is there any other options?

Comment: It is not correct to save an image in a database. Rather, you must save the image path

Comment: Do u have any examples on the, are we need to encrypt images?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/9357668/6017001

Comment: Encrypt or compress? @tTechDubey

Comment: When we save images to the path, we should compress the image or we can save without compress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way is to store the image as a file not in the database and then store the path or enough of the path to uniquely identify the image in the database.

To store an image you have to store it as a BLOB based upon a byte[] (byte array);
However, using the Android SDK, there is a limitation that only images less than 2MB can be retrieved even though they can be saved.

- *Technically you could store the image as a hex, binary, octal string but that would be more complex, less efficient and even more restrictive.*. So really *you have to store it as a BLOB* is not completely factual.

It's also actually pretty useless storing images (or any large files) with SQLite or most structured databases as there is little that you can do with the data query wise.

You actually save a BLOB via SQL using something like :-

```
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES(x'00FF01EF');
```

- i.e. 00 (0) is the first byte, FF (255) the 2nd,  01 (01) the 3rd .........
- note the above would only work for a table with a single column

However, the SQLiteDatabase **insert** convenience method does the conversion from the byte[] to the correct SQL (hex string) on your behalf.

So you'd typically use :-

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("your_column",your_image_as_a_byte_array);
your_sqlitedatabase_object.insert("your_table",null,cv);
```

You retrieve the byte array from a Cursor (result of a query) using something along the lines of

```
your_retrieved_image_byte_array = your_cursor.getBlob(your_column_offset_as_an_int); //<<<<<<<<< CursorWindow full error if the row cannot fit into the CursorWindow which has 2MB limit
```

You may wish to have a look at [How can I insert image in a sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954175/how-can-i-insert-image-in-a-sqlite-database/53954280#53954280), as this goes into more detail and has code that stores both images and paths (either one is stored based upon the image size, less then 100k, then the image is stored, else the path is stored) and additionally retrieves the images into a ListView. Additionally, although not recommended this is a way of getting around the 2Mb limit [How to use images in Android SQLite that are larger than the limitations of a CursorWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321154/how-to-use-images-in-android-sqlite-that-are-larger-than-the-limitations-of-a-cu)