# What should be the original ID of thumbnails in MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails methods?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the thumbnails of some images but the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#getThumbnail%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20long,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) is very unclear about what the **origId** should be. I have a simple method that takes a file as parameter and returns a drawable for thumbnails like this:

```
Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContext.getContentResolver(), Long.parseLong(Uri.fromFile(file).getLastPathSegment()), Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null); 
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), thumbnail);
return bd;
```

But I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long` exception whenever `getThumbnail` is called.

So how should I obtain the correct **origId** for an image file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way (this worked for me):

```
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

Comment: Yes that works, but I still like to find out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: hey just check once parameter is ur question statement right according to syntax

Comment: I think the parameters are all correct, see comment by frienza here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8383411/558991