# How can I improve the performance (first load time, scroll smoothness) of a GridView rendering many large images?

Tags: android, performance

My application allows users to take photos with their devices camera app, which are saved to an app-specific folder.

Then, users can choose to send any image they choose to one of their contacts, using their choice of their devices email app.

[image: Screenshot of "choose images to send" dialog]

Sadly the "choose images to send" dialog takes a long time to load initially, and is very "choppy" (frequent noticable pauses) when scrolling. I suspect that this is because the images are very large — pictures taken with my camera are around 2.3MB each. The initial screen (15 images displayed) thus needs to pull around 34.5MB off disk before it can render.

### GridView layout.xml

```
<!-- ... -->
<GridView
android:id="@+id/gvSelectImage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:numColumns="3"
android:gravity="center" />
<!-- ... -->
```

### Adapter getView()

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    File pic = pics[position];
    View checkedImageView = 
      LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.checked_image, 
                                           parent, false);
    final ImageView imageView = 
      (ImageView) checkedImageView.findViewById(R.id.checkableImage);

    /* LOAD IMAGE TO DISPLAY */
    //imageView.setImageURI(pic.toURI())); // "exceeds VM budget"
    Bitmap image;
    try {
        int imageWidth = 100;
        image = getBitmapFromFile(pic, imageWidth); // TODO: slooow...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    /* SET CHECKBOX STATE */
    final CheckBox checkBoxView = 
      (CheckBox) checkedImageView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBoxView.setChecked(isChecked[position]);

    /* ATTACH HANDLERS */
    checkBoxView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            CheckableLocalImageAdapter.this.isChecked[position] = 
              checkBoxView.isChecked();
        }
    });
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkBoxView.setChecked(!checkBoxView.isChecked());
        }
    });

    return checkedImageView;
}
```

`getBitmapFromFile()` is just adapted from the answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/633626. I note that the code there calls `decodeStream()` twice and might be doubling my I/O, but I think the dialog will still be too slow and too jerky even if I halve the amount of time to takes to render.

My testing phone is a standard Samsung Galaxy S II if that's relevant. I suspect older devices will be even slower / choppier.

What's the best way to improve performance here? I'm guessing a combination of an AsyncTask to load each image (so that the dialog can load before all images are rendered) and some sort of caching (so that scrolling doesn't require rerendering images and isn't jerky), but I'm lost as to how to fit those pieces in with the rest of my puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to work with [thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916159/android-get-thumbnail-of-image-on-sd-card-given-uri-of-original-image) instead.  Loading the whole image from the SD card will always be slow.  Only load the full version of the one(s) they really want to send.

This isn't to say that caching and async loading are a bad idea.  I'd change the code to work with thumbnails first, recheck performance, and then go the async route.  You can show a little spinner over the currently loading thumbnail to indicate that there's more to come.

Here's a [built-in class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html) to help you retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll play around with that class tomorrow when I'm at my desk. Does that MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails class work even if I've used .nomedia files to hide my apps images from the media scanner? The photos taken with the app will tend to be app specific, so I'd rather not have them show up in the gallery with all of the users other images, and so I've used .nomedia to hide them. The origId parameter ("original image id associated with thumbnail of interest") - I'm assuming that comes from the media store content provider?

Comment: OK, so I'm using a media store query to get image IDs from the media store, and it looks like I can't get image IDs (i.e. images aren't returned by the query) if they've been blocked from the media scanner with .nomedia files. It looks like /sdcard/Android/data/ (where my app data goes) contains a .nomedia file by default, so if I want to have automatic thumbnails I need to create a folder outside that hierarchy. Urg.

Comment: Alright, had to rewrite lots of stuff, but it's all working now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was away from SO for awhile.  Did you find a workaround to your issue of wanting the media store to ignore your images but still produce thumbnails?  If so, please edit my answer to include your findings :)

Comment: No, I just had to give in and have my apps images show up under the gallery (etc). I'm putting them under /sdcard/Pictures/<myapp> `(using getExternalStorageDirectory(PICTURES)`).

Answer (score 2):

Try loading your Images with a SampleSize into the GridView:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 7;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath(), opts);
```

More Info about the Options [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

And also you can swap the image loading into a Thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: The `getBitmapFromFile()` function I'm using already uses the `inSampleSize` option to scale the image, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Then put the getBitmapFromFile in an AsyncTask.