# How to handle large amount of pictures. which thumbnails sould be shown in android app?

Tags: android

I have a problem in my android application.
I use an application which make pictures with the build in camera of a phone/tablet.These pictures are sometimes quite large in size because of the high resolution of the camera.

Now i load the application and create a listView, where a small thumbnail of the picture is on the left side and on the right is some text.

I create the pictures in this way:

```
Bitmap a = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
         (float) 66.0, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
         (float) 48.0, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(a, width, height, false);
```

The problem is that this step take quite a long time.

Is there any way to make this faster?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916159/android-get-thumbnail-of-image-on-sd-card-given-uri-of-original-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make it faster, but you should not block the UI thread. See

1. AsyncTask (and many related questions like [Using AsyncTask to load Images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729133/using-asynctask-to-load-images-in-listview))
2. LruCache

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934983/1369222

It works great!

```
byte[] imageData = null;

        try     
        {

            final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            imageData = baos.toByteArray();

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

        }
```

Make sure you do this in an Async or a separate thread task so you don't block up the UI thread!