# Android Efficient Bitmap processing

Tags: android, bitmap, android-gallery

My scenario:

In my activity, I have to show 2 galleries, 1 with large image and another is a thumbnail(same exactly like default Gallery application).

My doubts:

1. I am planning to save as 2 images(1 with large size and another one with thumbnail size) in sdcard for fast processing. Is that good practice? since it will increase the size.
2. Or Shall I resize the large image during the getView method of BaseAdapter to small size for displaying in thumbnail gallery?

Which one is the good practice? I don't want to slow down my app.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/11/list-mediastoreimagesthumbnails-in.html) example.

I will suggest you that, put only your large image inside your sdcard. But at runtime, Android provides a good facility to get `Thumbnails` using `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails`.

**Edit:**

You can also get use [Loading Sample Sized Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). This will first create a sample size of your requirement. Then will give you a `Thumbnail` sized `Bitmap`.

*StackOverflowAnswers:*

1) [Get thumbnail of image on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916159/android-get-thumbnail-of-image-on-sd-card-given-uri-of-original-image)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to save my images without any format, so it wont get reflected in any of the gallery or photo applications. So, I cant get from MediaStore, as you explained.