# Address ImageView in SimpleCursorAdapter to show an image

Tags: android

This is part of my class that i supposed to select * from a sqlite table, show them in a listview that has 4 textviews and one imageview.

database has these columns:

```
sqlite> select * from events;
_id         title       location    date        img_loc                                                        
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------------------------------------------------
1           office      space       today       file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/OrangeClubPhotos/1370701231842.jpg
2           home        street26    june        null                                                           
3           wrjjfhwiru  rkljfewlr   487598347   file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/OrangeClubPhotos/1370702333785.jpg
4           jojo        jiji        today       file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/OrangeClubPhotos/1370702372846.jpg
5           office des  camp        right now   null                                                           
6           bed         no locatio  right here  null                                                           
7           home home   nyc home    June 8      file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/OrangeClubPhotos/1370714226736.jpg
```

so img_loc column has uri of the photos on sdcard.

```
    String[] from = new String[]{DbHandler.column_id, DbHandler.column_name, DbHandler.column_location, DbHandler.column_date, DbHandler.img_loc};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.photoInDb};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCurs = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listviewfinal, c, from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleCurs);
        simpleCurs.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int i) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

however, i dont know how to get on the ImageView so then i can decompress it due to this error "Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation." (i get this error when i try to use the code above unchanged.)

Comment: do you use BitmapFactory, if so, how?

Comment: my problem is before BitmapFactory and reducing images memory footprint. my issue is what code should i put in my codes above to get the Imageview to show my photos on sdcard from Uri in img_loc database column?

Comment: use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)

Comment: could you please gimme a snippet based on my code above?

Comment: just call decodeFile with param img_loc taken from your db cursor

Comment: please check the answer i posted below

Comment: findViewById
(R.id.photoInDb); => view.findViewById
(R.id.photoInDb);

Comment: still i get java.lang.NullPointerException at line iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: see if ImageView iv is null or not, if it is so probably R.id.photoInDb is wrong id

Comment: i've added a if statement => if (iv != null) { iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap); } //// but now i get out of memory error. looks like the bitmapfactory is not working

Comment: what if iv is null? you have to solve it first

Comment: in this case, i removed the null rows from db.

Comment: how big are your photos? what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916159/android-get-thumbnail-of-image-on-sd-card-given-uri-of-original-image

Comment: each photo is 2MB almost.

Comment: around 720p. or some as 1080p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however, i dont know how to get on the ImageView so then i can
>   decompress it due to this error "Out of memory on a 20155408-byte
>   allocation." (i get this error when i try to use the code above
>   unchanged.)

Remember that a Bitmap needs `width * heigth *` 4 bytes of memory. That could be a lot. So you have to downsampling it .

```
    BitmapFactory.Options()  opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inSampleSize = 4;
    Bitamap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathFromDb,  opt);
```

this way your bitmap will be width/4 and height/4