# Any fast way to get the list of folders which contains image?

Tags: java, android, image, directory, mediastore

I am working on a gallery. Here is the work flow:
(1) Display a list of folders which contain images
(2) Display a Gallery View that shows selected folder. (I can do it)

I know I can write a loop to find all image folders by look up every folders and files. But it is very slow.

OR

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor tmpCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null,     // Return all rows
            null, 
                    null);
```

But it is too slow too.

Is it any alternative way to do it?

The OS Gallery app can load the image folders in a reasonable time. I think it should be some better way to get the list.

Comment: Are you executing the query on the UI Thread?

Comment: Yes. But I execute it on a new thread, which one is faster?

Comment: Here's the actual answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195660/get-list-of-photo-galleries-on-android