# Android image gallery organization

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the categories that my default android gallery is organized into.

I've followed the basic code from this question : ([Android: How to query a list of bucket name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570521/android-how-to-query-a-list-of-bucket-name)), and editted it to display the buckets in a listview.

Using this method, I'm getting over 100 results of bucket names. However, in my gallery app, I only have about 7 categories (Camera Shots, All Images, All Videos, etc).

I know some of these buckets are somehow organized into the folders I see in the gallery app. For example all the buckets starting with DCIM probably go into the camera shots folder.

So I guess my question is, anybody know how the default gallery is organized?