# Query MediaStore on Android Q

Tags: android, sqlite, mediastore, android-10.0

I am fetching all albums of images using MediaStore and it was working fine before Android Q. But today I increased my compile version to 29 and it is throwing this exception :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT bucket_id, bucket_display_name, mime_type FROM images WHERE ((is_pending=0) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' ))) AND ( GROUP BY bucket_id )
```

Here is my code to query MediaStore :

```
    String[] PROJECTION_BUCKET = {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};

    String BUCKET_GROUP_BY = "1) GROUP BY 1,(2";
    String BUCKET_ORDER_BY = "MAX(datetaken) DESC";

    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(getUriOfType(type),
            PROJECTION_BUCKET,
            BUCKET_GROUP_BY,
            null,
            BUCKET_ORDER_BY);
```

As Group is not working in `Android Q`.

Any solution for this?

Comment: `"1) GROUP BY 1,(2"` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570521/android-how-to-query-a-list-of-bucket-name#answer-20486539

Comment: Get rid of that SQL, as it makes assumptions about the database structure that are not going to be valid on all versions of SQL. Do a simple projection for your three columns. Do the max calculations, grouping, and ordering in Java.

Comment: @CommonsWare If we still have to do this though java then there is no purpose of SQL

Comment: There is no requirement for any `ContentProvider` to be implemented using a SQL-compliant database. In particular, there is no requirement for `MediaStore` to be implemented using a SQL-compliant database. You used a hack, one that happened to work for a while for a few devices. Now you are complaining that your hack does not work. You should not have used the hack in the first place, as there has never been a guarantee that arbitrary SQL can be hacked into a `MediaStore` query. So, take this opportunity to fix your code and make it more reliable across devices and versions.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please explain this in answer with code? So i can understand better and accept your answer?

Comment: @CommonsWare Reddit found the original source of this snippet of code, it's from the Android Gallery3d: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/c8qtpg/the_commonsblog_leaky_apis_are_leaky/esrbqqi/

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Ugh. Hopefully, some current or former Google engineer reads my blog post and is embarrassed.

Comment: "Can you please explain this in answer with code?" -- I do not understand enough of what your code is trying to accomplish to be able to come up with the Java equivalent rapidly.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have read your [blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/07/03/leaky-apis-are-leaky.html) and what I understand is that I was doing this wrong from start.
Then my question is what is the proper way to group without using SQL as there is no clear guidance to do that.
What i am trying to do is fetch all pictures album wise.

Comment: Your current query does not do that. It retrieves bucket information, not information about pictures. The only thing in your projection related to a picture is `MIME_TYPE`. If your plan is to get the buckets, then make follow-on queries to get the pictures for an individual bucket, you can do that by removing `BUCKET_GROUP_BY` and `BUCKET_ORDER_BY` (and probably `MIME_TYPE`), as the resulting `query()` will give you a list of all buckets for all images.

Comment: That list will need to be de-duplicated, and since I haven't worked with buckets and `MediaStore`, I don't know if there is a better way of getting the unique set of buckets and bucket IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The **GROUP BY** no longer works on android 10(Q) and neither does the **COUNT**.
The following code snippet might help you.

```
String path = null;
String album = null;
String timestamp = null;
String countPhoto = null;
Uri uriExternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Uri uriInternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED
};
Cursor cursorExternal = getContentResolver().query(uriExternal, projection, "_data IS NOT NULL", null, null);
Cursor cursorInternal = getContentResolver().query(uriInternal, projection, "_data IS NOT NULL", null, null);
Cursor cursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursorExternal, cursorInternal});
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
    album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
    timestamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED));
    countPhoto = Function.getCount(getApplicationContext(), album);
    albumOrPhotoList.add(Function.mappingInbox(album, path, timestamp, Function.converToTime(timestamp), countPhoto));
}
cursor.close();
Collections.sort(albumOrPhotoList,new
// Arranging photo album by timestamp decending
MapComparator(Function.KEY_TIMESTAMP, "dsc"));
```