# Android Images.Thumbnails & Images.Media

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

i implemented two arraylists one with thumbnails (from Images.Thumbnails) and the other one with BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAMEs of each picture (from Images.Media).

Now i want to loop through it

```
for (int i = 0; i < thumbnails.size(); i++) {
    if (bucket_display_names.get(i).equals("WhatsApp Images")) {
        ......
    }
}
```

but i get an indexoutofbounds exception in the second line, meaning that the thumbnails array is greater than the one with the bucket_display_names... aren't they supposed to contain the same amount of pictures (in fact all of the phone)?

Comment: or you can just `for (int i = 0; i < thumbnails.size() && i < bucket_display_names.size() ; i++)`

Comment: ha! thx! i guess that works for the beginning..

Answer (score 0):

Check the way you are getting the list of the photo gallery. Maybe the following link can help you as a starting point: [Get list of photo galleries on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195660/get-list-of-photo-galleries-on-android?lq=1)

Comment: thats exactly how i do it. i tried this code on three newer phones (which (i assume) didnt have a lot of pictures on them) and it worked perfectly.
then i tried it on two "older" devices with >1000 pictures on them, and i got two times this exception... but i don'T see how a larger amount of pictures affects the code to fail in this one...

Comment: Use the log to check what's the thumbnails.size() value. Do you see anything wrong with the value? Does it match the real number of pictures?

Comment: ok thats what i'm gonna do, i dont have a phone with loads of pictures nearby right now. i will test it tomorrow. thanks so far.

do you have any idea, why it works on some devices and it doesnt on others?