# Create Android Gallery from Folder

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gallery

i am looking for a code that gets images from SDCard Folder and creates a Gallery shown in an activity. I found some sources on the web including on this forum but i can't resize the thumb.

Can you help me with a easy and working Source Code?

Here is something that works the way i want it to but loads images from drawable folder and i need from SD Card Folder.

http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android

Edit - CODE HAD BEEN ADDED

**MainActivity.java**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**row_grid.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**GridViewAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
/**
 *
 * @author javatechig {@link http://javatechig.com}
 *
 */
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        ImageItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

**ImageItem.java**

```
package com.javatechig.gridview;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * @author javatechig {@link http://javatechig.com}
 *
 */
public class ImageItem {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String title;

    public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

/**
 *
 * @author javatechig {@link http://javatechig.com}
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    }

    private ArrayList getData() {
        final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList();
        // retrieve String drawable array
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }

        return imageItems;

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having a specific programming issue?

Comment: i will try to use the given code from that link but i don't know how to get files from folder instead of drawable, which as you can see is saved as an array. so it is an array which contains @drawable/image1, etc

Comment: Well post the code _on_ the site please.

Comment: I added it in the question :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to retrieve images that the user has taken with the camera?

Comment: is, but taken with 1 day ago or so on, not to return it from the camera.
User takes picture, it is saved and after that if the user chose to see the pictures it will show the entire folder of the saved pictures :)

Comment: Yes, so you want to retrieve all the images that are already saved in the gallery?

Comment: yes that what i want to do :)

Comment: Try this. Sometimes its better to search ;-) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195660/get-list-of-photo-galleries-on-android

Comment: that looks like is not going to show the image, only image info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a path to the phone's image directory doing the following:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Since you want all the images, you can then get an array of files by calling [listFiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)
So:

```
File[] imageFiles = path.listFiles();
```

To convert each image, you can then use the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29), and iterate over the file array:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
```

So in your case, the getData() method would look like this:

```
private ArrayList getData() {
    final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList();

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File[] imageFiles = path.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageFiles.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFiles[i].getAbsolutePath())
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
    }

    return imageItems;}
```

Comment: so how should  private ArrayList getData() look like?

Comment: what if files location is SDCARD/test?

i tried 

String stringpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test";
File path=new File(stringpath);
and the same code like above (from you) and it crashes. What i do wrong?