# How can i get list of all directory from SDcard in android?

Tags: android

I want to get folder from SDcard which have multiple images.

I have done to get all folder but i want to get folder which have images.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.domore.folderlist.MainActivity">

    <!--<ListView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/listview"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
    <!--</ListView>-->
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private File file;
    private List<String> myList;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    GridView listview;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        File temp_file=new File(file,myList.get(position));

        if(!temp_file.isFile()) {

            file = new File(file, myList.get(position));
            Log.e("CLICK PATH",""+file);
            File list[] = file.listFiles();

            myList.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                myList.add(list[i].getName());
            }
            //adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

//            listview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,myList));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
//        super.onBackPressed();
        String parent = file.getParent().toString();
        Log.e("PATH",parent);
        file = new File(parent) ;
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        myList.clear();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
//        listview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,myList));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        myList=new ArrayList<String>();

        String root_sd= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString();

        Log.e("PATH",""+root_sd);
        file=new File(root_sd);

        File list[]=file.listFiles();

        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            myList.add(list[i].getName());
        }

        adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
//        listview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,myList));
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
}
```

Please, help me to solve out

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4196411/1878151 answer. Might help u.

Comment: you need to check folder is empty or not first

Comment: E.g. Whatsapp when i click on gallery then after all the folder of images is set into gridview.

Comment: How can i done this?

Comment: Please, Review my code first and tell me according to my code.

Comment: I done to get all the folder but i only get the folder which have images.

Comment: Are you getting my point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my application i write this code for load all photos:

```
Resolver = getContentResolver();

Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};
Cursor c = null;
SortedSet<String> dirList = new TreeSet<String>();

String[] directories = null;
if (u != null) {
    c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
}

if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst())) {
    do {

        String tempDir = c.getString(0);
        tempDir = tempDir.substring(0, tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
        try {
            dirList.add(tempDir);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
    directories = new String[dirList.size()];
    dirList.toArray(directories);

}

for (int i = 0; i < dirList.size(); i++) {
    File imageDir = new File(directories[i]);
    File[] imageList = imageDir.listFiles();
    if (imageList == null)
        continue;
    for (File imagePath : imageList) {
        try {

            if (imagePath.isDirectory()) {
                imageList = imagePath.listFiles();
            }

            if (imagePath.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US).endsWith(".jpg")
                    || imagePath.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US).endsWith(".jpeg")
                    || imagePath.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US).endsWith(".png")) {
                String path = imagePath.getAbsolutePath();
                PhotosList.add(path);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void searchImageFromSpecificDirectory() {

        String path = null;

        String uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
        // if GetImageFromThisDirectory is the name of the directory from which image will be retrieved
        String condition = uri + " like '%/GetImageFromThisDirectory/%'";
        String[] projection = { uri, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE };
        Vector additionalFiles = null;
        try {
            if (additionalFiles == null) {
                additionalFiles = new Vector<String>();
            }



            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                    condition, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                boolean isDataPresent = cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (isDataPresent) {

                    do {

                        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(uri));
System.out.println("...path..."+path);
additionalFiles.add(path);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines of code:-

```
 File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


    for (File f : file)
    {
        if (f.isDirectory()) { 
             file[] innerFiles = f.listFiles();

             for(int i=0; i< innerFiles.length;i++){
               Log.i("Name", innerFiles[i].getPath() + "");
              ///here you make the check that FOLDER consits IMAGE ofr NOT

              if( innerFiles[i].getPath().contains(".JPG") || innerFiles[i].getPath().contains(".jpg"))
                {

                 // YOU CAN PERFORM YOURS OPERATION HERE

                 }

             }
    }

        if (f.isFile()) { ... do stuff }
    }
            if (f.isFile()) { ... do stuff }
        }
```