# Is there a way to recognize app images from others on Android?

Tags: android, path, android-image

I'm developing an Android app that scans for images inside all the device folders and subfolders. I want it to return only photos or saved images but it is returning me also app images like buttons, arrows and others. I'm currently filtering for path name like `filePath.contains("cache")` and other similar to this, to remove cached images that I don't need. 
I wonder if there was a way to recognize app paths or app images correctly, like gallery apps do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it can help you, here's how an open source gallery app do it: https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Gallery/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/simplemobiletools/gallery/helpers/MediaFetcher.kt. (It's written in Kotlin)

Comment: Do you want to just scan for user-added images (i.e. gallery, camera, downloads, etc.)? If so, you can probably use the MediaStore content resolver to fetch and list those files. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196411/394933

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are checking for all the device image files by querying the MediaStore using the Uri **MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")**, you only need to ensure to place in the query selection **MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE**, and as selection arguments **MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE**. This way only the files which have been scanned by the OS as photo files will be returned.